# Django: Resize image on pre-save signal

Tags: python, django, django-models, python-imaging-library

I have a model that contains `ImageField` field and I want to resize provided image if it's dimensions are too big (over 600x600). My signal looks like this:

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.db.models.signals import pre_save
from PIL import Image

def resize_profile_picture(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    img = Image.open(instance.profile_picture)
    print(img.__dict__['_size'])
    if any([img.width > settings.MAX_PROFILE_PICTURE_WIDTH, img.height > settings.MAX_PROFILE_PICTURE_HEIGHT]):
        img.thumbnail(settings.MAX_PROFILE_PICTURE_DIMENSIONS)
        print(img.__dict__['_size'])

pre_save.connect(resize_profile_picture, sender=get_user_model())
```

Those prints shows that in fact the image is being resized, from (645, 374) to (600, 347), but the problem is that this thumbnail is not being saved and I still have picture in the original size. Since `thumbnail` operates on the same picture it is invoked on, I can't find any reason why it does not work, because according to the documentation, `thumbnail` returns NoneType so in my understanding it's not up to me to save modified picture or return it (But I tried nonetheless, no luck).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to save the `img` and reassign it to `instance.profile_picture`
like this:

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.db.models.signals import pre_save
from PIL import Image

def resize_profile_picture(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    img = Image.open(instance.profile_picture)
    print(img.__dict__['_size'])
    if any([img.width > settings.MAX_PROFILE_PICTURE_WIDTH, img.height > settings.MAX_PROFILE_PICTURE_HEIGHT]):
        img.thumbnail(settings.MAX_PROFILE_PICTURE_DIMENSIONS)
        img.save("thumbnail.png")
        instance.profile_picture = open("thumbnail.png")
        print(img.__dict__['_size'])

pre_save.connect(resize_profile_picture, sender=get_user_model())
```

Comment: And if I would like to avoid saving temporary file? Thanks to your solution, I managed to save images to BytesIO and then to `instance.profile_picture` using `InMemoryUploadedFile`, but wondering if there's any more straightforward way to assign images from PIL to ImageField.

Comment: You need a `File` to assign a value to `picture_profile` so I would say no. what you can do is create a function `thumbnail(img:Image) -> File` that hides the implementation away

Comment: If the answer solves your problem, would you mind accepting it?